# New Scientific Project in PyCharm

Tags: anaconda, pycharm

When creating a new scientific project in PyCharm, the default option to the Python interpreter is a fresh Conda environment:

[image]

Is it ok to change it to Virtualenv instead? Or will i face any kind of problem if i do that?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I just tried it and so far it's working. I didn't found any info if there's a problem using virtualenv, but i guess there isn't.